# PHP javascript like OR assignment

Tags: php

In javascript I am able to do this:

```
var act = POST['act'] || GET['act'];
```

This will give me the value of POST['act'] if it exists, else from GET['act'] else it will be falsy.

However doing this in PHP gives me true or false:

```
$act = $_POST['act'] || $_GET['act'];
```

Is it possible to get the value?

Comment: That linked answer needs an update for the PHP 7 null coalesce operator, which I'll add... http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce

Comment: Note that if you do `$_POST['act'] ?? $_GET['act']` with a the null coalesce and `$_GET['act']` is not set, you will get a _notice undefined index_. But it won't issue a notice for an unset `$_POST['act']` as the left operand.  Also, for this specific use case, you could maybe use `$_REQUEST` if your `variables_order` is set correctly. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski - I am actually on PHP 5.6, I'm not sure if I can use null coalesce. But your topic linked has other solutions thank you so much!

Comment: Ohhhh "conjuction" is what this is called! I was wondering that haha

Comment: The `||` as JS uses it and `??` is actually _disjunction_ rather than conjunction.  Conjunction would be `&&`.